# How can I port the Crypto++ library to an AIR Native Extension for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, actionscript-3, dll, air

Air Native Extensions can be very useful as it seems, but so far there there are almost no tutorials for their creation. The tutorials that I have found so far only target Android and iOS, not Windows.

Can someone describe in detail the proccess of creating a native extension for a library, say Crypto++ (on Windows)?

Also Crypto++ offers already-built DLLs. Can those be used directly in the native extension?

Thanks.

Comment: have you seen [native extensions for air page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @Eugeny89, I didn't notice that page http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html.